# How should I be appending multiple pages' tables into one CSV using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

## What is *not* working

Only the **last** page fetched is saved in the CSV, rather than **all fetched** pages.

## What *is* working

1. Desired content for a single page goes into a CSV just fine.
2. Loading the "next" page a certain number of times.

## Attempt/misunderstanding

I thought I could put code beneath
`for page in range(0, pages):`
into a loop. But that generates an IndentationError. I'm guessing I need to append each page, but am too new to understand how to connect everything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

## Code that produces CSV of last fetched page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

start = "http://awebsite.com/index.php?filter=&cur_page=0"
url = "http:/awebsite.comindex.php?filter=&cur_page={}"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(start).content)
pages = 2


for page in range(0, pages):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content)

table = soup2.find("table", class_ ="style10b")
output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.encode_contents())
    output_rows.append(output_row)
    
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

start = "http://www.bhpa.co.uk/documents/safety/informal_investigations/index.php?filter=&cur_page=0"
url = "http://www.bhpa.co.uk/documents/safety/informal_investigations/index.php?filter=&cur_page={}"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(start).content)
pages = 2
output_rows = []

for page in range(0, pages):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content)

    table = soup.find("table", class_ ="style10b")
    for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
        columns = table_row.findAll('td')
        output_row = []
        for column in columns:
            output_row.append(column.encode_contents())
        output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

I indented the collection of pages to be inside the pages loop, removed a typo, and got the output_rows on the top. This should do. For the indent error, be careful not to mix spaces and indents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas and concat

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.bhpa.co.uk/documents/safety/informal_investigations/index.php?filter=&cur_page={}"
pages = 2
final = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(0, pages):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content, 'lxml')
    table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table.style10b')),header =0, flavor = 'bs4')[0][:-2]
    final = pd.concat([final, table], axis=0,  ignore_index=True).fillna('')

print(final)
final.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', index = False)
```